# Facebook like button with auto URL - Joomla K2

Tags: php, facebook-like, joomla3.0, joomla-k2

I am developing a *website* which has a Blog, with multiple articles and URLs.
I need to insert **Facebook Like Button** with auto-detect *URL*. Is that possible?

Tried this CODE, but shows an error in *frontend*.

```
<div class="itemFacebookButton">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function(d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            </script>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has a tool for this or am I missing part of the question?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I guess that you're missing the _"dynamic"_ URL part... ;)

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? what exactly do you want?

Comment: I dont really know javascript very well so I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is _PHP_. In fact, I tried with _PHP_. So, facebook has a "tool" that if you blank `data-href=""` or even you simple delete it, the API auto recognize the URL, but what is printing in facebook profile (something like: _Cagentdog has liked this..._) links to something like this: `http://www.mysite.com/?fb_action_ids=730242877001182&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map={%22730242877001182%22%3A10150338332973910}&action_type_map={%22730242877001182%22%3A%22og.likes%22}&action_ref_map=[]`. So, I need to _print_ URL dynamically.

Comment: Oh, I see what you want know... I'm not sure how to do that but you might want to put that in the question to make it a bit clearer